# Setting bootstrap dropdown width less than 240px

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using [ngx-boostrap (AngularJS for Bootstrap)](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns) for drop-downs.

I an trying to have the `max-width` of lets say 120px for my dropdown, but I never gets small than 240px. Is there any reason behind it

This photo is the design

[image]

and this photo is what I am building

[image]

The html, js codes are as exactly as what is put in ngx-bootstrap, nothing fancy.
For css, I am putting `max-width=120px` on everything inside the dropdown-menu and itself and I can not make that smaller.

What is any remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track!  If you inspect `.dropdown-menu` you'll see it has the following value:

`min-width: 160px`

Since your `max-width` is less than that nothings going to happen; `min-width` is bigger and it's going to win.  Easiest solution is going to be to reset that value in your override:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 0px;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

Just keep in mind that any contents inside of `.dropdown-menu` that exceed this width will flow out of the container box.